# EMC CLARiiON - merge raid groups, retain LUN's

Tags: raid, storage-area-network, emc

Not sure this is possible, but...

Let's say you have two raid groups, each striped across 6 disks. Group 1 has 2 LUNs, Group 2 has two LUNs - is it possible to merge the raid groups (i.e. gain striping across 12 disks) and retain your 4 LUN's (intact)?

Might be something to run past my EMC engineers, but figured I'd toss it out on here for discussion. I know I can take an existing raid group and add disks, and it will integrate and expand the group - so I was wondering if I can take that to the next level and simply merge groups that aren't fully utilized, and increasing my I/O.

This is on a EMC NS-20

Comment: I followed up with EMC about this and they echoed the feedback I got here - that the only real way to is to migrate the LUNs off the group I want to merge, then merge those disks into the other group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change the RAID groups without removing all LUNs from the RAID groups.  You can move the LUNs to another RAID group, then destory the RAID groups, build the new one, then move the LUNs to the new larger RAID group.

That or create new LUNs on the existing RAID groups, and create meta-luns across that span the RAID groups, then migrate the LUNs to the meta luns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. I suspect that you would need to make a third group to hold them while you recreate the 12 disk group.

If you find out otherwise, it would be great if you came back and answered it so we all learn from it.

Comment: That is what I suspect as well, I will run it past EMC and see what their official answer is and post it here for everyone to see. Maybe there is some non-customer procedure for doing it, I know they have a laundry list of those that only their engineers can perform.